# Oracle Streams: ORA-0001 on dequeue?

Tags: oracle, stream, queue

In production every now and then we get an ORA-0001 error when dequeuing a message. We use:

1. Solaris 10
2. Oracle 10g
3. C++ application
4. PROC*C with dbms_aq package for queuing operations
5. Queues with XML payload
6. We handle a large volume of messages (1K/min).

Any clue why would a dequeue result in an ORA-0001 (unique constraint) error?

Update: adding code per request.

```
EXEC SQL EXECUTE
DECLARE
      message_properties dbms_aq.message_properties_t;
      dequeue_options    dbms_aq.dequeue_options_t;
      message_payload xmltype;
      tmpclob clob;
      dynamic_sql_string varchar2(512);

BEGIN
dequeue_options.wait := :iReadTimeout;
dequeue_options.dequeue_mode := dbms_aq.REMOVE;
dequeue_options.visibility := dbms_aq.ON_COMMIT;


IF :iBuffered = 1 then
    dequeue_options.delivery_mode := dbms_aq.buffered;
    dequeue_options.visibility := dbms_aq.immediate;
    :iNavigationMode := 0;
END IF;

IF :iDequeueOnly = 1 and :iQueueType <> 1 THEN
    dequeue_options.dequeue_mode := dbms_aq.REMOVE_NODATA;
    dequeue_options.wait := dbms_aq.NO_WAIT;
    dequeue_options.msgid := hextoraw(:pszDequeueMsgId);
ELSE
    IF :iNavigationMode = 0 THEN
       dequeue_options.navigation := dbms_aq.FIRST_MESSAGE;
    ELSE
       dequeue_options.navigation := dbms_aq.NEXT_MESSAGE;
    END IF;
END IF;


dequeue_options.deq_condition := :pszDeqCondition;

dbms_aq.dequeue(queue_name => :pszQueueName,
      message_properties => message_properties,
      dequeue_options => dequeue_options,
      payload => message_payload,
      msgid => :msgid );
IF dequeue_options.dequeue_mode <> dbms_aq.REMOVE_NODATA THEN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE dynamic_sql_string USING OUT tmpclob, IN message_payload;
        :gpoXmlClob := tmpclob;
ELSE
        :gpoXmlClob := message_payload.getclobval();
END IF;
END;
```

Comment: can you share any relevant code?

Comment: Check what is being received into dynamic_sql_string which you are executing in certain circumstances. Is it inserting something somewhere that is violating a unique constraint?